# How to use javascript functions inside javascript functions in Siddhi App?

Tags: javascript, function, siddhi

I have been working on a Siddhi App. Inside this app I have JavaScript functions. 
I have found a problem when trying to use the function inside the function. 
Lets say:

```
define function sum[JavaScript ] return double {
   return data[0]+ data[1];
}
define function getthesum[JavaScript] return double {
   var s = sum(5,1); 
   return s; 
}
```

But when I do this, "sum" is not defined appears in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The function defined here can be only used within Siddhi queries, and they cannot be used in an integrative manner with each other.

E.g you can do

```
from FooStream 
select sum(a,b) as total
insert into BarStream;
```

And here the getthesum() is not correct.